# Perspective text in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, text-wrap

I have a building I made in InDesign and I need to put text on it. I need the text to look like it is on the wall and I'm having issues trying to figure this out. The white space is where the text is suppose to go.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to Illustrator or Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

Graphic development is done within Adobe Illustrator or Adobe Photoshop (or an equivalent graphics program based on your needs/preferences) as @AndrewH was hinting towards and then brought into InDesign.

While you do have basic transform controls when dealing with text in InDesign, you'll find that it lacks the ability to transform text to provide an accurate perspective for what you're trying to achieve.

**How to shear text in InDesign:**

[image: Right click context menu]
*Select which text you want to transform by right clicking it.*

[image]
*Using the shear (right click the text you wish to transform) option you can only control one axis, and it can become a tedious process as you lose control of the source content when provided the pop-up menu to begin adjusting values.*